# JAX-RS : HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type

Tags: jax-rs

I got this error when making an ajax request to my WebService : 
HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type
I tried to add the good MediaType (Text/Html, i think), but it doesn't work. I have still this error. What could this be, do you think ?
Thank you !

My request :

```
    $(document).on('submit','.form-add-edit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var idDisruptive = $(e.target).find('input[name=idDisruptive]').val();
        var url = "api/disruptive";
        var method = "POST";
        if (idDisruptive){
            url = url + '/' + idDisruptive;
            method = "PUT";
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method : method,
            data : getDisruptiveParams(),
            success : function (response){
                console.log('EDIT')
                console.log(response);
                //editDisruptive(response);
            },
            error : function(response){
                console.log('EDIT ERROR')
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

The Web Service :

```
@Stateless
@Path("disruptive")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_HTML, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class DisruptiveFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Disruptive> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "StoryGeneratorPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public DisruptiveFacadeREST() {
        super(Disruptive.class);
    }

    @POST
    @Override
    public void create(Disruptive entity) {
        super.create(entity);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    public void edit(@PathParam("id") Integer id, Disruptive entity) {
        super.edit(entity);
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the content-type on the jQuery request. If you don't, it will default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. And just because you add `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)` doesn't mean that JAX-RS will not how to convert the form data to `Disruptive`. There need to be a `MessageBodyReader` to handle that conversion, which there isn't. Same goes for `MediaType.TEXT_HTML`. Just adding that means nothing if there is no converter to handle the conversion. Remove those two. What you want is to handle JSON conversion, and there should already be a `MessageBodyReader` included in the EE server that will convert JSON data to arbitrary POJOs.

So for the jQuery, just add

```
$.ajax({
  contentType: 'application/json'
})
```

That should solve the problem.